# Pandas Python 3.11 Pivot FutureWarning: default value of of numeric_only in DataFrameGroupBy.sum is depricated

Tags: pandas, pivot, python-3.11

Have a large mixed table of text and numbers and am pivoting a smaller set from the larger table.  It appears that when I updated to Python 3.11 I'm receiving an FutureWarning on my pivots now.

```
df = df.pivot_table(df2,index=['My_text_Column'], aggfunc='sum').reset_index()
```

The code runs fine but results in

> FutureWarning: The default value of numeric_only in
> DataFrameGroupBy.sum is deprecated. In a future version, numeric_only
> will default to False. Either specify numeric_only or select only
> columns which should be valid for the function.

What is the updated code I should use?

Answer (score 0):

I hit this exact same problem with the code here https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pivot-tables-in-pandas/

Adding
'values = "Marks" to

```
# pivot_table() method
display(pd.pivot_table(df, index = ["ID", "Name"]))
```

so that I had:-

```
display(pd.pivot_table(df, values="Marks", index = ["ID", "Name"]))
```

Removed the warning.
I tried using:-

```
display(pd.pivot_table(df, numeric_only = None, index = ["ID", "Name"]))
```

But got the warning
`TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'numeric_only'`.
So specifying 'numeric_only = True' doesn't actually seem to be a thing in pivot_table().

The pandas documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html didn't make it any clearer either.

Answer (score 0):

```py
display(pd.pivot_table(df, numeric_only = None, index = ["ID", "Name"]))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Tried:  df = display(pd.pivot_table(df, values="Marks", index = [text_col1','text_col2'])) and got an error:

NameError: name 'display' is not defined

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that there is non-numeric data in df. In order to call the pivot_table function, this non-numeric data in 'values' should be replaced:

```
df.replace('non numeric string', np.nan, inplace=True)
display(df.pivot_table(df, index = 'ID', columns='Name', values='Data'))
```

Comment: I want to keep the non-numeric data.  The way it is grouping is working fine.  Is there a way to do the pivot table and keep the text while grouping the numbers?